# Installing selinux headers

Tags: linux, headers, centos-5, selinux, glibc

I'm trying to build the newest version of glibc (2.19) on CentOS 5.6 and I've run into some issues

The documentation of glibc says that I need at minimum the linux kernel headers 2.6.19 (even if this is not the kernel I am using). I tried to install the headers using

```
make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/root/kernel/headers/
```

This command finishes without complaining about anything going wrong but when I go to build glibc after configuring with

```
/root/glibc/glibc-2.19-source/configure --prefix=/root/glibc/glibc-2.19/ --enable-kernel=2.6.18 --with-headers=/root/kernel/headers/include
make -j 12
```

make encounters an error

```
#include <selinux/selinux.h> selinux/selinux.h: no such file or directory
```

I think the selinux headers ought to be in /root/kernel/headers/include because I read on wikipedia:

> It has been integrated into the Linux kernel mainline since version 2.6, on 8 August 2003

I looked in /root/kernel/header/include and the is no folder named selinux

My question is: Should the selinux headers be installed with the rest of the kernel headers and if so how should I get them to be installed?

I'm using gcc 4.9.0 and binutils 2.24. My current version of glibc is 2.5. My kernel version is 2.6.18

Note that I am not willing to accept much downtime and do not want to change active kernel versions or replace my current glibc altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find out what package provides that specific file issuing:

```
$ yum provides */selinux.h
```

I don't have a CentOS 5.9 around to try it, but most probably the result will be `kernel-devel` and `libselinux-devel` packages.

You should always use the kernel headers that match the kernel you are using.

Comment: In Debian it's libselinux1-dev.

Answer (score 0):

While compiling [`systemd`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/v253) I ran into error

```text
In file included from ../src/shared/env-file-label.c:7:
../src/shared/selinux-util.h:13:10: fatal error: selinux/selinux.h: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <selinux/selinux.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Package `libselinux-dev` worked on Ubuntu 22

```text
$ apt install libselinux-dev
```